# E-Mail Plugin - "strapi-provider-email-nodemailer"

Tags: strapi

I have a question about Strapi e-mail plugin. I would like to use Nodemailer.
When I test it with Postman, I get the error 500. Did I write the PostScript JSON in the wrong format?

[image: Setting on my Strapi]

[image: statusCode: 500]

[image: Format Error]

Thanks in advance!

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to DMehaffy (Not Strapi Employee)!

The setting was wrong in Postman. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you selected body data type **text** but inside the body you are passing JSON data.
please select **JSON(application/json)** instead of text.